# how to block the button from enter the website

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm working on my html source to get the user to input their email address in the textbox and allow them to click on the submit button to enter the website.

When a user did not enter their email in the textbox, I want to know how do I block them from enter the site and how do I display the warning text that says "Error, you have not eneter your email address" to force them to enter their email address first before they could be able to click on the submit button to enter the site?

Here is the html source:

```
<p class="leadstyle-text" style="display: block;">Enter your email address here:<br />
<input class="default-value" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address..." value="" />



<div id="form">
 <div id="ldheLabel5" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 228px; width: 450px; height: 16px; text-align: center;">
 <a class="button1 leadstyle-link" href="www.mysite.com" id="submit-btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Get Access Now! 
   <span class="arrow" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
 </a>
```

**Edit: When I try this, it is not doing anything:**

```
<form action="" onsubmit="validateEmail()">

<input required class="default-value" id="Email" name="Email" style="position: absolute;   left: 21px; top: 170px; width: 423px; height: 61px;" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address..." value=""/>

<input type="submit" value="Now access">


</form>


<script>
function validateEmail() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var email = document.getElementById('Email');
  if(email.value) {
    window.location="http://www.google.com/";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use required attribute on input elements, this will prevent submit. But better yet, you can use input type=email if you want email validation on top of that. enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

use required attribute on the input field . (Warning this is a html5 attribute and will not work in older versions of browsers)

```
<input required class="default-value" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your     Email Address..." value="" />


<form action="" onsubmit="validateEmail()">

<input required class="default-value" id="Email" name="Email" style="position: absolute;       left: 21px; top: 170px; width: 423px; height: 61px;" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address..." value=""/>

<input type="submit" value="Now access">


</form>


<script>
function validateEmail() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var email = document.getElementById('Email');
  if(email.value) {
    window.location="http://www.google.com/";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, when i don't input my email address in, i can still click on the button to enter the site. i want to force to input my email address in the textbox while display the warning. how can i do that?

Comment: how about using a button and window.location as mentioned above

Comment: thank you very much for that, when i put the email address and when i click on the submit button, it is not doing anything. please see my update post in my first post.

Comment: Ok Please see my full edited working example above. Hope it helps . Thanks

Comment: i can't see you have edited with the update post? i tried it but it don't work.

Comment: @user3757279 thank you. i can see it is working. i'm using this `<input class="button1 leadstyle-link" id="submit-btn" type="submit" 
style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 228px; width: 424px; height: 
66px; text-align: center;" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Get Access Now!">` so how i can use the `<span class="arrow" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>` in the value?

Comment: how i can use this `<a class="button1 leadstyle-link" id="submit-btn" type="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Get Access Now! 
   <span class="arrow" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
 </a>` as a submit button to work?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form . In general it is not recommended to submit a form using anchor tag but a solution to it is available on the link above

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault() before checking the email value.
As described here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/