# HTML input 'required' is not working even in a form

Tags: html, forms

I have a textbox and a checklist with the 'required' attribute inside, and when I press a button to go to the next page without filling both inputs, they don't validate if they are filled.

```
<form id="form" method="" action="">
   <input type="text" name="dressPrice" id="price" class="control" onkeypress="return numberFilter(event)" dir="rtl" onpaste="return false" required />
   <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" required /><label class="tac-label"> I accept the <a href="terms-and-conditions.html" class="tac-link">terms and conditions.</a>

   <a href="buy-step-02.html" class="btn is-small" type="submit">Search</a>
</form>
```

The weirdest part, is that I have another HTML page with a form, and the 'required' attribute on the inputs over there works just fine. Anyone has an idea of why this happens?

I don't think it's a compatibility issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use anchor to submit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `input` insted of `a` . 
Also there was a missing `</label>`

```html
<form id="form" method="" action="buy-step-02.html">
   <input type="text" name="dressPrice" id="price" class="control" onkeypress="return numberFilter(event)" dir="rtl" onpaste="return false" required />
   <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" required /><label class="tac-label"> I accept the <a href="terms-and-conditions.html" class="tac-link">terms and conditions.</a>
</label>
   <input  class="btn is-small" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```