# Custom form submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, mailchimp

I'm making a custom subscribe button for my MailChimp list. I can't seem to get my button linked up with the form input method though.

```js
var subscribe_button = document.querySelector(".fi-mail");

subscribe_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 subscribe_button.classList.remove("fi-mail");
  subscribe_button.classList.add("fi-check");
});
```

```css
* {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #fff;
}

html {
 background: linear-gradient(134.72deg, #EB4B92 0%, #CA76E3 100%);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 text-align: center;
}

form {
 background: transparent;
 height: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: -25px 0 0 -150px;
}

input {
  background: transparent;
 float: left;
 padding: 14px 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 margin-left: 25px;
 width: 220px;
}

form a {
 float: right;
 background: #4db6ec;
 border: 0;
 line-height: 38px;
 height: 38px;
 width: 38px;
 margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}

form a:hover {
 background: #75c8f3;
}

form a.fi-check {
 background: #aed43e;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 transition: all 0.6s ease;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

form a.fi-check:hover {
 cursor: default;
} 

.a-thing {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: .9em;
 text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -195px;
}

.a-thing a {
 color: #eeffbc;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.a-thing a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.eot");
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.woff") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.svg#GeneralFoundicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class*="fi-"]:before {
  font-family: "foundation-icons";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fi-check:before {
  content: "\f126";
}

.fi-mail:before {
  content: "\f16d";
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   opacity:  .2;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   opacity:  .2;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
   color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<form action="https://fulfillingtheprophecy.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9c9cbcbf400c4df4622eef40f&amp;id=0ae3f9ab0f" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
  <input type="email" placeholder="ava@example.com">
  <a type="submit" class="fi-mail"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Just to cover all the bases - have you reviewed [Host Your Own Signup Forms | Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/host-your-own-signup-forms/)?

Comment: @esqew I just re-reviewed that, I know how to get the form to work just not with keeping the anchor styling when I change the anchor to a button or input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer as I think it does a good job answering your question: ([Is it safe to use anchor to submit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form)).

**Short Answer**: Either of the following should work for you in place of your anchor tag.

`<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />`

or

`<button type="submit">Submit!</button>`

Comment: Used your link to get a solution that worked for me, as well as the link @esqew shared to get the right tags for the input field.