# PHP: How to return to same spot on page after clicking Submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a web page with 20 different questions on the index page.  The user clicks "Submit" after every question.

```
<form action="./index.php" method="post" id="element">
```

The information is then posted and sent to the database.  Of course this makes the index page reload and display at the very top of the page.  This makes for a lot of scrolling.

Is there a way to make it so the page reloads and scrolls back down to the place where it left off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use anchor to submit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the anchor didn't work.  It reloaded the page and I was back at the top.  I want to reload the page and be right back where I was.  Is there some way to mark the page and have it reload to that spot?

Comment: If you are clicking the link, you are able to define the anchor right where the user clicked. Just put the anchor there then reference it in the form action.

Comment: There it goes!  I used the answer that 62 votes the first time but that didn't work.  It's the answer that got 3 votes that worked.  Had to add the token to the form and a name to the anchor.  Thanks a lot Mech!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Be sure to turn that 62 in to a 63.

Comment: the best option would be to use ajax to submit each form preventing page reloading and avoiding to do this kind of hack. Better user experience and better architecture for your application @David

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7983093/4101210

To use an anchor to submit a form would require the use of JavaScript to hook up the events. It's not safe in that if a user has JavaScript disabled, you won't be able to submit the form. For example:

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">Submit!</a>
</form>
```

If you'd like you can use a `<button>`:

```
<button type="submit">Submit!</button>
```

Or stick with what we all know:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

You can style all three of them, but the latter two don't require JavaScript. You probably just need to change some CSS somewhere if you're having border issues.

Answer (score 0):

The code that answered my question was by joshua bissot.  He showed how to put the token in the action and name the anchor to make this work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918771/12140988

```
<!-- add the anchor token at the end of your action statement -->

<form method='post' action='this_page.php?put_peram=token#anchor_name'>
<input type='submit' value='click here'>

<!-- put the anchor right above where you want the page to  index -->

<a name="anchor_name></a>
```