# Logout function is not functioning as intended

Tags: html

The logout button is registering but when you click it but it isn't logging out of the page and there are no errors or output

```
    <!-- Logout Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form class="user" method="post" action="petdata.php">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" type="logout_function" name="logout_function">Logout</a>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why did you use PHP Tag in your question..? I see just HTML. And what is really the problem...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use anchor to submit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983076/is-it-safe-to-use-anchor-to-submit-form)

Comment: the way is done this form will never submit any data to petdata.php, is there any JS script attached to logout button to submit the form ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `<a>` into `<button type="submit ...></button>` or `<input type="submit" ...>`, it should submit the data into the form where's the action and method set.